# gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

i have one spinner which display data from database. now i want to display data in grid view which selected in spinner.

so plz give good solution for my this question.

Comment: Sorry your question is a bit unclear could you try to rephrase it? Could you post some code?

Comment: i have one spinner that display data from database, and there is one gidview. so in that gridview display those data which selected in spinner.

Comment: andBecause of less space in comment. i can not send my code to you..

Comment: @SAM Bhadani, you can edit your question.

Comment: Whether you want to get the value selected from the spinner?

Comment: if you have any simple Gridview Demo code which based on database then plz send to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the value selected from the spinner and display it in grid 
View,if so try this..

```
Spinner spin_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_type);
spin_type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String selected Value=array_type[arg2].toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Where array_type your String array that is having complete "DATA"..

You will get the Value selected in the Spinner in "Selected Value"..